How to extract a word in a string between two similar characters" with VBA?
I need to extract Wööörd_03 from this string:
"https://Word01.com/Word_02/Wööörd_03/Word_04/Word_05=0"
My code doesn't, cause I get different results:
Sub ExtractWord()

Dim sString As String, pString As String, iString As Long, jString As Long

sString = "https://Word01.com/Word_02/Wööörd_03/Word_04/Word_05=0"

iString = InStr(sString, "/")
jString = InStrRev(sString, "/")
pString = Mid(sString, iString + 21, jString - iString - 29)

MsgBox pString

End Sub

Does anyone know a better way to ALWAYS extract the word between the 4th and 5th slashes?
Thanks

Look into SPLIT()
pString = Split(sString,"/")(4)


Just in case you have the possibility of escaped characters in your string, you may need to do a replace "/" with a vbnullstring to remove and eascaped '/' chars from the string before the split.  e.g. Split(replace(sstring,"/", vbnullstring), "/")

Regular expression is also an option
sString = "https://Word01.com/Word_02/Wööörd_03/Word_04/Word_05=0"

' Create the regular expression object
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

' Define the pattern with capture group
re.Pattern = "\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)"

' Execute the regular expression on the input string
Set match = re.Execute(sString)

' Check if there's a match
If match.Count > 0 Then
  Debug.Print match(0).SubMatches(0) ' 1st capture group
End If

